# Rails 3 Routing problem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I convert the Rails-2 application into Rails-3. In my Rails-2 routing i have the routes like the below

#### Rails 2

```
map.connect 'example/:action/:id.:format', :controller => 'Test',:q =>'example-string'
```

**Note:** This is working well in Rails-2 application; when the url comes with `/example` it redirect to Test controller's index action with the parameter `q="example-string"`

#### I converted the above to support Rails-3 routes:

```
match 'example(/:action(/:id.(:format)))',:to => 'Test',:q=>'example-stirng'
```

The problem is I got the Routing Error `/example` not found.

How can i change the Rails-2 routes into Rails-3 routes?

Answer (score 0):

You almost got it right. Should be

```
match 'example(/:action(/:id.(:format)))',:controller => :test, :q=>'example-stirng'
```

`:to => "foo#bar"` is a shortcut for `:controller => :foo, :action => :bar`